# symfony 2, form_rest(form) shows collection fields

Tags: forms, symfony, collections

My form has 3 collection fields:

```
$builder->add('affiliates', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new AffiliateForm(),
    'allow_add' => true, 
    'allow_delete' => true, 
    'by_reference' => false,
    'options' => array(
        'affiliate_types' => $options['affiliate_types'],
        'business_types' => $options['business_types'],
    ),
));

$builder->add('other_businesses', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new OtherBusinessForm(),
    'allow_add' => true, 
    'allow_delete' => true, 
    'by_reference' => false,
));

$builder->add('welfare_activities', 'collection', array(
    'type' => new WelfareActivityForm(),
    'allow_add' => true, 
    'allow_delete' => true, 
    'by_reference' => false,
    'options' => array(
        'welfare_activity_types' => $options['welfare_activity_types'],
    ),
));
```

In the template I show each subform field separately one by one, like below:

```
<td class="t1c5" >{{ form_widget(affiliate.location) }}
                  {{ form_errors(affiliate.location) }}</td>
```

At the end of the form I did:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

But it causes to display the following words at the end of form, when given collection is empty: "Affiliates", "Other businesses", "Welfare activities". 
So the question is:

1. Why those words are displayed on the form?
2. I can do the following to avoid the above issue:

   ```
   <div style="display:none;">{{ form_rest(form) }}</div>
   ```

   Is it correct way of dealing with the problem (maybe i can make a field hidden or whatever)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

those words are displayed on the form because you forget :

```
{{ form_label(affiliate.location) }}
…
…
```

According to the doc :

**form_rest(view, variables)**

This renders all fields that have not yet been rendered for the given form. It's a good idea to always have this somewhere inside your form as it'll render hidden fields for you and make any fields you forgot to render more obvious (since it'll render the field for you).

Answer (score 0):

```
    {{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```